# Pass variables with append jquery

Tags: jquery

Just getting back into jQuery and JS and I am forgetting the basics..

```
J(".thSort").click(function() {
    var num = J(this).parent().index() + 1;
    var thName = J(this).parent().children().html();
    J("table td:nth-child("+ num +"),th:nth-child("+ num +")").hide('slow');
    J('.filterToggle').append(' <a href="#" onClick="J("table td:nth-child("+ num +"),th:nth-child("+ num +")").show();"> Show "thName" </a>');
});
```

Essentially this is hiding columns when I click an X with the class thSort. When it hides a column I want it to write to a div I have elsewhere what items have been hidden so people can "show" them again.

Comment: What isn't working about what you have?

Comment: You should mock this up in JSFiddle.net so that we can help you out.

Comment: It writes the link to the filterToggle div as show "thName" and not show Agency (or whatever the variable was)

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BfG2e/  You can see what I am trying to do when you click the X with the white bg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pluckerpluck found your issue, but there is one more spot you used " instead of ', which is why "thName" is being shown instead of the column name.

```
J(".thSort").click(function() {
var num = J(this).parent().index() + 1;
var thName = J(this).parent().children().html();
J("table td:nth-child("+ num +"),th:nth-child("+ num +")").hide('slow');
J('.filterToggle').append(' <a href="#" onClick="J("table td:nth-child('+ num +'),th:nth-child('+ num +')").show();"> Show ' + thName + ' </a>');
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
J(".thSort").click(function() {
var num = J(this).parent().index() + 1;
var thName = J(this).parent().children().html();
J("table td:nth-child("+ num +"),th:nth-child("+ num +")").hide('slow');
J('.filterToggle').append(' <a href="#" onClick="J("table td:nth-child('+ num +'),th:nth-child('+ num +')").show();"> Show "thName" </a>');}
```

As you used ' to start the string you have to use ' to break from the string to add variables.

Comment: This didn't work for me, there is a fiddle above.. maybe you can show me in there? If not thanks for the attempt! You guys all rock.